# Why choose SATA 2 over 3?

Tags: bios, sata

Just installing an SSD into an HP Probook 6560b and noticed that Samsung Magician states that the drive is connected with SATA 2. I looked in the BIOS and SATA 2 (3.0gbps) was chosen, rather than SATA 3.

This was the default setting.

Why would SATA 2 be default rather than 3? I realise HDD will generally not saturate SATA 2 or benefit from 3, but why not leave 3 as the default instead? Does SATA 3 use more power, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It could simply be that your HDD is only SATA 2 ready.

Otherwise...

SATA 2 has far less compatability issues than SATA 3. Not to say SATA 3 has many issues at all but SATA 2 will work with just about anything. If your drive is unformatted, it is possible that the motherboard just detects a generic storage device and so switches to a 'compatability mode'.

Comment: Good points. I have set the laptop to SATA 3 with the original factory hard drive installed with no issues (just to see what happens of course).

Comment: Please let me know when you have any negative results @RASB